# Remove Page Range Metadata from PDF

Tags: pdf, metadata, exiftool

I've merged multiple PDFs that were generated with Latex. These PDFs contain page ranges, meaning "real page" 40 and "real page 41" are simple transitions - e.g. adding an item to a bullet list. So when going to page 41 in my PDF viewer I end up at "real page" 42.

Since multiple files have been merged these page ranges conflict themselves in my PDF viewer, see here (page 1 points to "real page" 260, 309, 338 etc.):

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've tried following [this guide](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/07/how-to-edit-pdf-metadata-tags-on-linux.html) and [this github gist](https://gist.github.com/hubgit/6078384) to get rid off PDF metadata.

```
qpdf --linearize pages.pdf
# or
exiftool -all:all= pages.pdf
```

Both didn't work. Is there any way besides printing to PDF to get rid off this page metadata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [pagelabels-py](https://github.com/lovasoa/pagelabels-py).  It appears to be a python script that can edit PDF Page Labels.  It gives this [example command](https://github.com/lovasoa/pagelabels-py#user-content-delete-existing-page-labels-from-a-pdf):
`python3 -m pagelabels --delete file.pdf`

Comment: I have not actually tried this out, your question just got me interested in the idea.  And now, I may look into actually doing this to a bunch of my pdfs.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you very much.